# Is it possible to estimate parameters from data with MCMC using squared error, with no probability model of the observed data?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

I am familiar with using MCMC with a likelihood to estimate model parameters.

However, I have recently been in a new field which usually gets point estimates of parameters using least squares rather than likelihoods. A recent paper moved to MCMC, but did not mention any probability model of the data. I contacted one of the authors and they said that their MCMC estimates were "based on a least squares analysis", and that no probability model (i.e., no likelihood) was required to perform their MCMC.  Is this really possible? My understanding of MCMC is that a likelihood (at least an approximate one) is required to perform the MH step. If it is possible to perform MCMC using least squares, could somebody point me to a basic introduction of how that works?

Thank you

Comment: Strictly speaking, MCMC only requires a probability density function, $p(\cdot)$, which need not be a posterior density. There exist Bayesian approaches where the likelihood is replaced by a utility function, as in [Bissiri et al. (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6430), in which case MCMC can be applied to this pseudo-posterior.

Comment: Can you reference/link the paper you mention?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Apologies for the slow response, this is the doi of the paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.trf.2021.04.006